# Need to give row class after each row in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, row

I am trying to display 3 results in each row. 1 result contains image,title and description. If description is a lengthy one, the 4th result in the second row will break. So I need to give  after each row. I tried the following code, but didn't work.Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="row">
    @if(count($reports['data']) > 0)
        @foreach($reports['data'] as $reportsUser)

            <div class="col-md-4 wow">
                <article class="post post-2 post-2_mod-c clearfix">
                    <div class="entry-media">

                        @if($reportsUser['image'])

                            <img src="{{ asset(App\Http\Controllers\Controller::getThumbPath($reportsUser['image'])) }}"
                                 alt="Foto" class="img-responsive" style="width:360px;height:192px;"/>
                        @else

                            <img src="{{asset('images/no_image.jpg')}}" alt="Foto" class="img-responsive"/>

                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="entry-main">
                        <div class="entry-header">
                            <h2 class="entry-title ">{{$reportsUser['title']}}</h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <p>{!! str_limit($reportsUser['description'],127,"....") !!}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="entry-footer"><a href="{{ url('view-report/'.$reportsUser['id'])}}"
                                                     class="btn-link clsComClrRed">Continue Reading</a></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>

        @endforeach
    @endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `@foreach` statement to:

```
@foreach($reports['data'] as $i => $reportsUser)
```

Then, just before your first `@endforeach` (and after `</div>`), add:

```
@if ( $i % 3 == 2 )
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
@endif
```